# (Ruby on rails) Validation on a Log-in form by formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, formtastic

Hello I am new in Ruby on Rails and I am using Formtastic to make my forms. Is it possible for the input field for the user's username's validation for uniqueness will not be implemented for my Log-in form but for all other forms, the uniqueness validation, will be implemented? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Formtastic doesn't do any client side validation. In fact, Formtastic doesn't do any validation. The model is responsible for validation. It sounds like you might be using a User model for a login form, which I would suggest is incorrect. Consider a UserSession model (without a database table) like the one provided in AuthLogic, or consider not using Formtastic on such a simple form like a login.